# MySQL Group by Max() value from another table by date (one per day)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Data:

```
id, name, surname, date, result
```

Stats:

```
id, average, type
```

I'm trying to get a table result with one record per date with maximum average from table 'stats'.

E.g.

```
23  John  Smith  21-01-2017  Pass -  98%  A
17  Tom  Dell    20-01-2017  Pass -  78%  A
9   Will Jones   19-01-2017  Pass -  85%  A
```

So far I tried some queries like (with no success):

```
SELECT * FROM 'Data'
JOIN 'Stats' ON Data.id = Stats.id
INNER JOIN
        (  SELECT  MAX(average) 
           FROM 'Stats'
           WHERE Stats.type = 'A'
           GROUP BY Data.date
        ) 'Data' ON Stats.id = Data.id
ORDER BY Data.date DESC
```

How can I make it work? Thank you

Comment: I assume the single quotes around the table names are transcription errors.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a really bad data model.  Why is the date in the `Data` table and not the `status` table.

In any case, you are dealing with "date"/"average" pairs so you need to join the tables together twice:

```
SELECT d.*, s.*
FROM Data d JOIN
     Stats s
     ON d.id = s.id JOIN
     (SELECT d2.date, MAX(s2.average) as max_average
      FROM Data d2 JOIN
           Stats s2 
           ON d2.id = s2.id
      WHERE s2.type = 'A'          
     ) sd2 
     ON sd2.date = d.date AND sd2.max_average = s.average
WHERE s2.type = 'A'
ORDER BY d.date DESC ;
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's a little complicated structure, not ideal solution, but it's more complex than that. 
The solution that you provided is stopping at
Unknown column 'd.id' in on clause